# Using LOGD/LOGI as cout

Tags: android-ndk

I have an application I am porting and it uses cout for the majority of it's logging. Is there a way I can write a definition that converts the cout << stringVal to LOGD(stringVal);

something using

```
#IFDEF __ANDROID__
```

or equivalent would be prefered

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind:

1. Write a replacement `cout` that writes to the Android log file instead of stdout, then `#define cout acout`.
2. Pull [dalvik/vm/StdioConverter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/jb-mr2-release/vm/StdioConverter.cpp) into your project and use that to copy stdout to the Android log.

This is assuming that you can't simply use [log.redirect-stdio](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) (e.g. your device isn't rooted).